# Binary Search Tree - make remove function in virtual machine with Linux

Tags: c++, search, tree, binary

This is my own BST(binary search tree functions)

When I compile, it occurs segmentation error(core dumped)

which part is wrong?

I think there is no logic error

Please see my codes and give me advices

```
void Tree::remove(int data){
TreeNode *cursor=this->rootnode;

while(1){
    if(cursor == NULL){
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<data<<" remove failed"<<endl;
        return; 
    }
    TreeNode *tNode;
    int value=cursor->getData();
    if(value==data){
    if(cursor->getRight() != NULL && cursor->getLeft() != NULL){
        tNode = findMaxNode(cursor->getLeft());
        int num=tNode->getData();
        cursor->setData(num);
        cursor=cursor->getLeft();
        remove(num);
    }
    else
    {
         tNode = (cursor->getLeft() == NULL) ? cursor->getRight() : cursor->getLeft();
            free(cursor);
        cout<<data<<" remove success!"<<endl;
            return;
    }


    }
    else if(data>value){
    cursor=cursor->getRight();
    remove(data);
    }
    else if(data<value){
    cursor=cursor->getLeft();
    remove(data);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to post a [mcve], the promblem may be in the part of the code you didn't post. Also read this: [ask].

Comment: And you also need to learn how to use your debugger, which greatly helps to spot this kind of errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should to use (more) the recursivity to solve your problem. I hope that this code will help you.

```
void Tree::remove(int data)
{
    if(this->rootnode == NULL)
    {
        cout<<data<<" remove failed"<<endl;
        return; 
    }

    remove(this->rootnode, data);
}

void Tree::remove(TreeNode* &cursor, int data)
{
    if (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if (data == cursor->getData())
        {
            remove(cursor->getLeft(), data);
            remove(cursor->getRight(), data);
            delete cursor;
            cursor = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW he _already_ uses recursivity. But this is clearly much cleaner and simpler code.